# show form as dropdown to button (vuetify)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a `v-btn.`

When clicked on it, I want to have a dropdown to it. I don't want the dropdown to be a list, but the form with 3 labels and 3 text fields. Each label for each textfield.

Problem 1) When showing labels and textfields, they are all at the same line(horizontally). how do I make label and textfield below it?

Problem 2) WHen that dropdown appears and I put mouse on textfield, dropdown completely closes. I only want to close it when i click the button which also resides on that dropdown at the end of the form. how do I not close it when clicked on it ?

P.S. I am using v-menu for dropdown.

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem 1**
Can you please provide a small example of your code?
In Vuetify you can just use a [`v-text-field`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields#text-fields) and give it a label via the `label` prop.

**Problem 2**
You can set [`close-on-click`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus#menus) and [`close-on-content-click`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus#menus) to `false` to prevent the dropdown from closing.

Small example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      menuOpen: false,
      firstname: "",
      lastname: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    save() {
      alert(`Your name is ${this.firstname} ${this.lastname}!`);
      this.menuOpen = false;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#app { height: 400px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-menu offset-y :close-on-click="false" :close-on-content-click="false" v-model="menuOpen">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <v-btn v-on="on" class="ma-4">BUTTON</v-btn>
        </template>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-text>
            <v-text-field label="First Name" v-model="firstname"></v-text-field>
            <v-text-field label="Last Name" v-model="lastname"></v-text-field>
          </v-card-text>
          <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn color="grey darken-2" @click="menuOpen = false" dark>CANCEL</v-btn>
            <v-btn color="primary" @click="save">OK</v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-menu>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Vuetify text fields have a prop named "label" - if you bind the label text to this prop it'll [automatically appear above the text field](https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1010). Otherwise, if you for some reason want to create your own label, just wrap both the label and input in a v-layout OR wrap the label and input in the same element (e.g. div) and make sure the label is a div

```
          <v-flex xs12 sm6>
            <div>test label</div>
            <v-text-field
              v-model="title"
              :rules="rules"
              counter="25"
              label="Outline"
              outline
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-flex>
```

2) the menu has a "close-on-content-click" prop that defaults to true, which you can set to false. This will prevent the menu from closing on click